# Isomorphisms between infinite dimentional spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be an infinite dimensional vector space. Can we find an isomorphism between $V$ and $V \oplus V$. If the answer is positive then how this isomorphism can be constructed?

Comment: Stating that this is generally possible might require, for example, the axiom of choice

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Not really, as it is just a matter of a bijective map between a set and twice that set (rather than between a set and its square).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft still, that might be an issue when the dimension is strictly larger than $\mathfrak c$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Really? I thought that never required choice.

Comment: We already need choice to have a basis of $V$ in the first place ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Ahh, good point.

Comment: Ohh, and if I recall correctly, this can in fact fail in the absense of choice, since then it is consistent to have a vector space that is not finite dimensional but where all proper subspaces are. But clearly the direct sum of two copies of such a space loses that property.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen sure, but my point is that the isomorphism can't necessarily be constructed explicitly (as you seem to have mentioned in your answer)

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft see a relevant discussion [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/864851/all-sets-have-bijection-with-cartesian-products-of-subsets)

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft If you can find a reference (and also the amount of choice needed) that would be an interesting addition

Comment: @Hagen I seem to have misremembered. I was thinking of the properties mentioned at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/142609/linear-algebra-without-choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes (given the Axiom of Choice). Let $\{v_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a basis of $V$. As $I$ has infinite cardinality, $|I|=|I|+|I|$, i.e. there exists a bijection $f\colon (I\times\{0\})\cup (I\times\{1\})\to I$.
Then $(v_i,0)\mapsto v_{f(i,0)}$, $(0,v_i)\mapsto v_{f(i,1)}$ is a bijection between a basis of $V\oplus V$ and the given basis of $V$, which extends linearly to an isomorphism of vector spaces.
Note however that per reference ot the Axiom of Choice this isomorphism cannot in full sense be called "constructed".